# WebScraping in Excel using Selenium - problem with readonly attributes

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, readonly-attribute

I would like to remove the readonly attribute in a website. I can only use Excel VBA with Selenium in order to do this.

The code in the webpage is the following:

```
<input type="text" name="fchFin" id="fchFin" readonly="" value="2023-05-26" maxlength="10" size="10" onblur="validarFecha(this);">
```

Comment: What did you already try, and what specific problem did you run into?

Comment: Please show your VBA code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Dim iput As WebElement, rO As Boolean
Set iput = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@name='someName']")
driver.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", iput 
rO = iput.Attribute("readonly")`
```